# How would I do a searchbar filtering with usecontext

Tags: reactjs, filtering

> Blockquote

**import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Pizza } from "./Pizza";

```
import { GlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalState";

export const PizzaList = () => {
  const { pizzas, getPizzas } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPizzas();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h3>History</h3>

      <ul className="list">
        {pizzas.map((pizza) => (
          <Pizza key={pizza.id} pizza={pizza} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};**
```